# NoSQL data architecture: deep or wide?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, database-design, nosql

I'm  preparing to use Firebase's Firestore and, having watched [the videos](https://youtu.be/Ofux_4c94FI?si=049J_ULXC99PPCmZ) and played around with it, I have a theoretical question:

The data I want to store there has a "deep" aspect to it, something like: An African Elephant is descendant of Gomphoterium, which is descendant of Paleomastodon, which descends from Meoritherium.

You can store a deep relationship in Firestore by chaining collection -> document -> collection -> document etc., but that seems awkward (an afterthought? a hack?)

Alternatively, I suppose you could keep the whole zoo flat (one level of collection and documents within) and store the genealogical ancestries as keys in each animal's document (parent-1, parent-2 etc.) But then some animals will not have parent-N (the trees are not balanced), or some parents will appear in different parent-N keys for different animals. Either way, the client will need to do query gymnastics and the point of using Firestore is lost.

So deep structure or flat? I'd appreciate peoples' thoughts on this.

Comment: I'd recommend keeping what you call the flat model, and only use subcollections for separate data types, or when you either need/want to partition data (for example for access control, or for write throughput).

Answer (score 1):

In general, when it comes to NoSQL databases, it's recommended to keep the data as flat as possible. However, when it comes to Firestore, it's not always the case. You can indeed use a flat structure as well as a deep structure. Firestore is as fast as it is at level 1 and is also at [level 100](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#databases), which is the maximum level.

For your use case, I would create only one collection and set for each animal the descendants. For example, I would set for the Gomphoterium, the Paleomastodon as the lower level, and the African Elephant as a higher level. So the Gomphoterium is in between the Paleomastodon and the African Elephant. I hope you get the idea. This is helpful because you'll be able to know where in the hierarchy an animal is placed.

Comment: Hey Yanay. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?